# How to send a job to a network printer in Python

Tags: python, printing, network-printers, escpos

all How i can send file/job to a network printer in Python.
I tried the following code but this is used to send only the text, but i want to send pdf/file to the printer.

```
    from escpos.connections import getNetworkPrinter    
    printer = getNetworkPrinter()(host='192.168.0.20', port=9100)

    printer.text("Hello World")
    printer.lf()
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can’t print pdf but images. Convert your pdf to image and print that.
See [the docs for escpos](https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/escpos.html)  and [pdf2image](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image)

Comment: Actually **escpos** is not working, can you please suggest me any other library which is working ?

Comment: actually, nothing goes to the printer.. printer receives nothing. on internet.